# rename the cobertura.ser file in tomcat/bin when i deployed my web application in tomcat

Tags: file, tomcat, maven-2, war, cobertura

i deploed my web application instrumented with cobertura through war file in tomcat 6,it works well!
In th path tomcat/bin i found d:/dev/../module1/target/cobertura/cobertura.ser,normal according me.
Now i want know,how can i rename this file(d:/dev/../module1/target/cobertura/cobertura.ser) to cobertura.ser automatically when i deploy the web application
PS:my web app is multi modules web app.
thanks for answers!

Comment: yes,am using maven2.thanks for your answer!

Comment: "Now i want know,how can i rename this file(d:/dev/../module1/target/cobertura/cobertura.ser) to cobertura.ser " -> you want to rename cobertura.ser to cobertura.ser ??